# Showing one-one onto

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I wanted to find the values of $a$ for which the function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=ax+\sin x$ is bijective. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: a bijective, continuous function is monotonic: it is either strictly increasing, or strictly decreasing.

edit: As mentioned in the comments, monotonicity just gets you injective; $\arctan(x)$ for instance is monotonic but not bijective.  You also need surjectivity: you have to show your function actually *does* have all of $\mathbb R$ as its range.

Comment: Monotonic only implies injectivity, a continuous monotonic function which is not bijective on $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ would be $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x/(x+1)\quad&\text{if }x>0\\x/(1-x)&\text{if }x\le0\end{array}\right.$$ So while your statement is correct, you should mention that a surjectivity proof is needed.

Comment: Hm, point.  A clamp argument should work for that...

Comment: Can surjection be shown by showing $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}f(x)=\infty, \lim\limits_{n\to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$

Comment: @Anupam: That and continuous gets you surjective, yes.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$f'(x)=a+\cos x$$
so $f$ is increasing iff $a\geq 1$.

Comment: Well, $0\ge-1$ so $a=0$ should work, but $\sin x$ is not bijective on $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$

Comment: Something went wrong here.  This suggests that $\sin(x)$ itself ($a=0$) is bijective...

Comment: Oops. I have just fixed.